# Select needful class from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have some class inside body from which I need to select class `hs-content-path-history-of-data-pagetopic2013`

```
<body class="blog-template  hs-blog-id-1815512257 hs-blog-listing hs-content-path-history-of-data-pagetopic2013 hs-blog-name-history-of-data-page"></boby>

var bodyClass = $('body').attr('class');
// select needfull class from var above

if(selectedClass === 'hs-content-path-history-of-data-pagetopic2013'){
    // it works!
}
```

How can I select the `hs-content-path-history-of-data-pagetopic2013` from body class?

Comment: what is our actual need?

Comment: bodyClass returns me - "blog-template  hs-blog-id-1815512257 hs-blog-listing hs-content-path-history-of-data-pagetopic2013 hs-blog-name-history-of-data-page". from this string I need to select this class "hs-content-path-history-of-data-pagetopic2013" - and then, when I get It i need to compare it whith "hs-content-path-history-of-data-pagetopic2013" and perform the action after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the body, or any element, has a certain class, you can use `hasClass`

```
if ( $('body').hasClass('hs-content-path-history-of-data-pagetopic2013') ) {
    ...
}
```